# Is the direct product $k \times k$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

If $k$ is a field, then is the direct product $k \times k$ is a field? If so why?

Comment: This is also a multiple duplicate. For example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/229836